# Open PDF and 3DPDF inside our application from sdcard of device in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to open PDF and 3DPDF internally application from sdcard of device in android.

Answer (score 0):

try{

File file = newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Foxit/yogamags.pdf");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

startActivity(intent);

}

catch(Exception e){

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to open PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

Comment: Beware, that "solution" will work `IF` and only `IF` the device running the code have an activity that can handle PDF. If not, it will thrown an ActivityNotFoundException https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html

Comment: Agreed with above comment.But can be open in web browser also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Budius but i want to open pdf internally in my app.